# Please specify a non-zero error margin

Tags: google-earth-engine

Actually, when I'm trying to do a landuse supervised classification with Google Earth Engine, a strange message appears :

> Collection.geometry: Unable to perform this geometry operation.
>   Please specify a non-zero error margin.
>       in , line 11
>       in , line 24

What is wrong with my code?

```
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-06-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first());
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min:0, max: 3000});
var classNames = turban.merge(twater).merge(tforest).merge(tagriculture).merge(tsoil);
print(classNames);
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: classNames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30


});

print(training);
var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands,
  });
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);
Map.centerObject(classNames, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 4, palette: ['red', 'blue', 'green','yellow','orange']},
'classification');
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

i've fixed the problem by reducing the size of the training data

Comment: It would be useful to also add the limit, above which it fails